# Open the specific folder by usig Excel VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

I got difficulties with VBA code.

I have a Excel file named Database for GL and I want activate this file by using VBA code then I want to Vlookup some information from this file to my current working file.
I have the directory for file.

C:\Users\user\Desktop\Avromed QSC\GL_Analysis

Avromed QSC - is file folder

GL_Analysis - is file folder

Database for Gl - is excel file.

Please, help me to define proper VBA code for this action.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how I can write proper VBA code to open excel file using directory which I have written above?

I want to look up some information from the Excel file. for this action firstly I need active this file automatically by VBA code. But I cant write proper code for this action

Comment: Have a look at **`DIR`** functionality in VBA. Try this and provide the VBA code that you have tried. If there is still an issue with the code, we can help. As you are a new user, please remember that this is not a code writing service. We will help with what you have tried but not write the code for you